# jhipster gateway and registry UI customization

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-registry, jhipster-gateway

I am looking for (hoping for) some kind of guide to customizing the JHipster Gateway and Registry UIs so that I can integrate them nicely into my organization.

Is there such a guide, or are we left to check out the source code and start hacking?

Comment: You're on your own, generated code is only a starter

Comment: jhister-registry and jhipster-gateway are not generated, these are more product than customizable code. The only thing that makes them customizable is access to their code.

Comment: You're right for the registry but not for a gateway: its UI is generated from the entity definitions of your microservices.